# How to download images with apache on windows

Tags: android, symfony, wamp, retrofit2, picasso

(sorry my english is very poor)
I develop an android app.
I want to download/upload images for my user. i use Retrofit and Picasso on my android app and on my local server i use Symfony. when creating user on my app, i store user's info on MYSQL DABASE with apache and i want to store user's profile picture on a directory like **C:/wamp/www/My_app/mobil/photo/user_id/**. Now my first question is i don't nkow how to send picture from android app to this folder.
And the second problem is i have tried to download some pictures from apache to android app using Picasso library. i use this cod :

```js
Target target = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            user.setPhoto(HelpLoader.getBitmapAsByteArray(bitmap));
            Log.e("PICTURE ok", "********************");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
            Log.e("PICTURE FAIL", e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {}
    };
    String url = "http://192.168.8.100/My_app/mobil/photo/" + user.getId() + "/profil.jpg";
    Picasso.get().load(url).into(target);
```

i get a 403 Error and when i test the url with a browser apache show this error
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /My_app/mobil/photo/2/profil.jpg"
but when i try simply to access to the folder /My_app/mobil/photo/2/, i don't have this error.
please help me.
i use :
- apache 2.4.23
- Symfony 3
- Retrofit 2 for send user's informations
- Picasso for the pictures

Comment: is My_app folder in the root directory of your apache server??

Comment: Yes, My_app is it

Comment: Please nobody can help me ????